# Regarding the expectation of a function of two random variables...

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove the following:

> If $X,Y$ have discrete p.m.f $p(x,y)$, then $\forall$ real-valued function $g$,
> $$E[g(X,Y)]=\sum_{x}\sum_{y}g(x,y)p(x,y))$$

I wasn't sure if my argument was valid, so I come here for a proof check and potential pointers:

> **Attempt**
>
> Suppose X,Y are s.t they can take on values $x_1,x_2,...$ and $y_1,y_2,...$ respectively. Further, let $g(x_i,y_j)=k_{(i,j)}=k_m$, $i,j,m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $(i,j)=m$. Then we have
> $$\sum_{x_i}\sum_{y_j}g(x_i,y_j)p(x_i,y_j)=\sum_{m}\sum_{i:g(x_i,y_j)=k_m}\sum_{j:g(x_i,y_i)=k_m}g(x_i,y_j)p(x_i,y_j)$$
> $$=\sum_{m}\sum_{i:g(x_i,y_j)=k_m}\sum_{j:g(x_i,y_i)=k_m}k_m p(x_i,y_j)$$
> $$=\sum_{m}k_m\sum_{i:g(x_i,y_j)=k_m}\sum_{j:g(x_i,y_i)=k_m}p(x_i,y_j)$$
> $$=\sum_{m}k_m P\{g(X,Y)=k_m\}=E[g(X,Y)]$$

Comment: It seems to me that your argument and its proof are correct.

Comment: Ah wonderful! I get easily thrown off by multivariate, so I wasn't sure if my (i,j)=m argument would hold up.